# jquery: toggle and css display status

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a div which is hiding/displaying using jquery's toggle method using 'fast'. Right after the toggle occurs I log the css display status of the div toggled and if it goes from being displayed to hidden the status shows up as 'block'...

But per the jquery docs it should now be 'none':

When a duration is provided, .toggle() becomes an animation method. The .toggle() method animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously. When these properties reach 0 after a hiding animation, the display style property is set to none to ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

```
$(this).parents('#accordionContainer').find('div.accordionContent').toggle('fast');
    console.log($(this).parents('#accordionContainer').find('div.accordionContent').css('display'));
```

My console log  output:

block

jquery....min.js (line 162)

Edit: Just thinking out loud here but wondering if I need to do a setTimeout between the toggle and display check, maybe of 1 second or so? Better yet, does toggle return a isFinished message or something like that?

Comment: Found the answer here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215751/jquery-toggle-doesnt-change-child-element-style-of-visible-elements-when-parent

Comment: Found the answer here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215751/jquery-toggle-doesnt-change-child-element-style-of-visible-elements-when-parent

Answer (score 0):

"Right after" calling toggle, the method is animating asynchronously. Since it's adjusting the width and height to do the animation, it has to declare the CSS as display:block. Once the animation is completed, the CSS should go to display:none as you expect.

You can have a piece of code be called after the animation is complete by supplying a callback parameter to the toggle() function. For example:

```
$(this).parents('#accordionContainer').find('div.accordionContent').toggle('fast', 
    function() {
        // This is called when the toggle animation is complete
        console.log( $(this).parents('#accordionContainer').find('div.accordionContent').css('display'));
    }
);
```

In JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ggfe4

Comment: I was writing that into my code as you were typing it here. : D But I am still getting 'block' returned...

Comment: This might be it: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11436 : according to the post, if the parent is display: block; then items within it will get a display value of the parent, whether they have been toggled to display: none or not...why jquery would do that or think that is helpful is weird. Not sure if this is accurate or not but this seems to be what I am experiencing, as accordionContainer is the parent and always shown, while accordionContent is a child and can be toggled.

Comment: Take a look at this JSFiddle. Using jQuery 1.7.2 the code works as expected and 'none' is displayed. http://jsfiddle.net/Ggfe4/